# Why does the add to cart button not work correctly?

Tags: woocommerce

There is an add to cart button:

`<button type="submit" class="button add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart adding_to_cart" data-product_id="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" data-product_sku="<?php echo esc_attr($sku) ?>">add to cart</button>`

if it has:
`data-product_id="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>"`
ajax working, but attributes are no longer added (the product is added without reloading, but without attributes)

if remove it:
`data-product_id="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>"`
attributes are added together with the product, but with page reload

How to add to cart without reload and with attributes?
I suppose that I need to get the variation ID and add it, but I don’t know how to do it

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Where are you using this button? shop page or single page?

Comment: @Bhautik single page

Comment: I think when you click on add to cart selected variation id is not passing through the ajax.

Comment: @Bhautik probably so, but how to fix it, this is trouble

Comment: Can you share site URL?

Comment: Ok, You mentioned `the product is added without reloading,` but it's a reloading page.

Comment: @Bhautik yes, now I added ```data-product_id="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>"``` and now without reloading, but without attribute

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
function custom_add_to_cart_script() {
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            $('.ajax_add_to_cart').attr('data-variation_id',$('input[name="variation_id"]').val());

            $('input[name="variation_id"]').change(function(event) {
                $('.ajax_add_to_cart').attr('data-variation_id',$(this).val());
            });

        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'custom_add_to_cart_script');
```